# where better to get user IP in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, ip

Where is it better 
in bootstrap.php or app_controller.php

it's needed for geolocation.

Comment: What do you use the IP for and how?

Comment: standard php code of apache environment REMOTE_ADDR

Comment: I don't understand why it makes a difference. The remote IP will be the same anywhere all throughout the app, and since you just need to read it from the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable, it doesn't make any difference *where* you read it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are using the IP for. If you need it in all parts of your code, then the app_controller is the place to put it. If you only need it for log in for example, then put it in the users_controller.

That being said, it may be better to write a session variable and then it is available wherever you need it without the code overhead.

Comment: thank cdburgess 
we needed for geolocation, so where is it better? <br>

Comment: I would put it in the session variable. The best place to do that probably would be the app_controller. Check for the session variable ($this->Session->read('ip')), if it doesn't exist, then add it. Also, if you are going to use the geo_location frequently, I would store that there too. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 19):

In 1.x use

```
RequestHandlerComponent::getClientIP()
```

it already covers all problems you might be facing

and yes, "at the point in time at which at which you need it"

For 2.x it's best to use

```
$this->request->getClientIp()
```

from inside the controller as documented on http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#requesthandlercomponent

Comment: for cake2 it would be CakeRequest::clientIp() by the way

Comment: also see http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2013-should-public-cakerequest-clientip-as-static for it to be clean and  E_STRICT. hopefully my changes get accepted.

Comment: Please change the answer accordingly. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#requesthandlercomponent

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

or

```
$remIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

at the point in time at which at which you need it. That way you can be sure it's current, although I'm not sure if it could get stale. It's there in the server all of the time, so there's no concept of when to assign it - just get it when you need it.

Comment: firstly cake has a RequestHandlerComponent::getClientIp() for getting ip addresses. If for some reason you do not want to use that, at least use env() for getting server variables. http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/request-handler-component/#l-474

Comment: Wherever possible I avoid the use of RequestHandler. There is absolutely nothing wrong with using PHP.

Comment: ...unless the component is already in use for something else, loading it simply to wrap this bit of PHP would be bad programming.